# How to play video in android application

Tags: android

i am trying to develop an android application in which i want to show movies trailers to user using url from json. The URL can be from Youtube dailymotion or from any other source. Kindly help how can i make such a video player which can play any video in my application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By the help of MediaController and VideoView classes, we can play the video files in android.

**Example-**

activity_main.xml -

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

        <VideoView  
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />  

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java -

```
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.widget.MediaController;  
import android.widget.VideoView;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);  

                //Creating MediaController  
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);          

              //specify the location of media file  
           Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/1.mp4");          

              //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
           videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
           videoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
           videoView.requestFocus();  
           videoView.start();  

    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  

}
```

Comment: Video View give me error from youtube video "Cant play this video"

Answer (score 0):

Define VideoView in your Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After that Define this code in your Activity

ViedoView videoview;

```
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);


try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });
```

It's working for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
  VideoView videoview;

  videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videodetail_view);

  videoview.requestFocus();
```

try 
     {

```
final MediaController mediacontroller = new   MediaController(Activity.this,true);

            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);

            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);

            // mediacontroller.canScrollHorizontally(0);

     scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    mediacontroller.hide();
                }
            });


            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
            //  videoview.setActivity(this);
            // videoview.setShouldAutoplay(true);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });


 In XmlLayout
  <VideoView android:id="@+id/videodetail_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/noimage"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: i tried to use Video View in my application but when i load video from youtube it give me error "Cant play this video".